# How do I modify PATH in the VSCode integrated terminal without overwriting VSCode's own additions to the PATH?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode's Remote SSH feature to develop on a remote Linux server. One of the features of VSCode Remote SSH is that when using the VSCode integrated terminal, a special path is injected into `$PATH` in the terminal environment to allow you to use the `code` command on the remote server and have it open files in your existing VSCode session. For instance, from the VSCode integrated terminal:

```bash
[user@server my-workspace]$ echo "$PATH"
/nethome/user/.vscode-server/bin/6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b/bin/remote-cli:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/tools/matlab/r2019a/bin:/usr/apps/bin:/nethome/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/matlab/r2019a/bin:/usr/apps/bin:/nethome/user/bin:/nethome/user/bin:/tools/matlab/r2019a/bin:/usr/apps/bin:/nethome/user/bin
[user@server my-workspace]$ which code
/nethome/user/.vscode-server/bin/6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b/bin/remote-cli/code
[user@server my-workspace]$ code README.md
[user@server my-workspace]$ # README.md is now open in my existing VSCode session
```

However, when using VSCode in this particular workspace, I want to prepend a directory to the `$PATH`, for instance, the `build/bin` folder inside the workspace. For this reason, I created a `.vscode/settings.json` in my directory with the following contents:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "PATH": "${workspaceFolder}/build/bin:${env:PATH}"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this seems to overwrite VSCode's own addition to the `$PATH`:

```bash
[user@server my-workspace]$ echo "$PATH"
/nethome/user/my-workspace/build/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/tools/matlab/r2019a/bin:/usr/apps/bin:/nethome/user/bin:/tools/matlab/r2019a/bin:/usr/apps/bin:/nethome/user/bin
[user@server my-workspace]$ which code
/usr/bin/which: no code in (/nethome/user/my-workspace/build/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/tools/matlab/r2019a/bin:/usr/apps/bin:/nethome/user/bin:/tools/matlab/r2019a/bin:/usr/apps/bin:/nethome/user/bin)
[user@server my-workspace]$ code README.md
bash: code: command not found...
```

Is there a way to prepend my desired directory to the `$PATH` in the integrated terminal without overwriting the one injected by VSCode (`.../bin/remote-cli`)?